# get text value within anchor, but not other html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have captured an `<a>` tag and have it as a jQuery element. I would like to get the text that comes before it's `</a>`. But the problem is there is a table in there too.

```
<a>
 Text content I want
 <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
      lots of tds
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</a>
```

`text()` gets me everything, `text(":not('table')")` is apparently nonsense, `text().not("table")` returns nothing. How can I get this singular string of text inside of the anchor?

Comment: `$('a')[0].childNodes[0].textContent` should get you that, but why do you have tables inside links? :))

Comment: and if it's after the table too you can just loop through the childNodes collection and determine if the node is text or not

Comment: @onetrickpony Can you submit this as an answer. It's clean and simple. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is get the text of the element without getting the text of the child element.

Basically, you want to clone the `<a>` element, select it's children, remove the children (the table), and then capture the remaining text.

```
$('a').clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

Here's a fiddle where I simply alerted the result of the above code to the browser.:
http://jsfiddle.net/6pBqY/

I'm not sure this will work in all cases but it seems to work just fine with your example.

I derived this solution from this website, which you can visit for more information: 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Comment: Thank you. Why is this better than onetrickpony's solution. His seems less complex.

Comment: It's better because it gets you the content from all text nodes. If you had any text after `</table>`, that would count as a different node.

Answer (score 1):

U must just remove html tags from string. I think this variant its better:

```
var content = document.getElementByTagName('a').innerHTML;  var text = $(content).text();
```